# Suggest as Answer button

Tags: feature-request

Why don't we have Suggest as Answer button near every answer?
I see a lot of unanswered questions (With answer, but not marked) everyday.
It would be great if system can Accept Answer as usefull automatically if there is like 10 suggestions or something.

I am sorry in advance if this is already suggested, but I really think this could be usefull here (I'm talking about all communities in StackExchange).

Comment: `I am sorry in advance if this is already suggested` - don't be sorry. **Do** some research before asking something that has been asked many many many many many many times before.

Answer (score 11):

The semantics (i.e. meaning) of an accepted answer is:

> The Question asker has determined this question to be most helpful to **them**.

That's all it means. And I don't see a reason to change it to mean:

> Some members of the community have decided this is the best answer of the bunch.

Why?

Because we already have that. They are what upvotes are for.